# Cannot load Symfony2 form extension

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Symfony doesn't seem to load any classes found in `AppBundle\Form\Extension` while [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html) suggests it should after registering it as a service.

My extension looks like this:

```
<?php
//src/AppBundle/Form/Extension/FieldTypeExampleExtension.php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class FieldTypeExampleExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->setAttribute('example', $options['example']);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['example'] = $options['example'];
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'example' => null,
        ));
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'form';
    }

}
```

and it is registered as a service like so:

```
#services.yml
AppBundle.ExampleExtension:
    class: AppBundle\Form\Extension\FieldTypeExampleExtension
    tags:
        - { name: form.type_extension, alias: field }
```

When I try to utilize this extension, I get the following error:

```
    $builder->add('city', 'text',array(
        'required' => false,
        //'help is made available by https://github.com/simplethings/SimpleThingsFormExtraBundle
        'help' => 'separate multiple cities with a comma. Example: Chicago, Miami, San Fransisco',
        'example' => 'that those them'
    ))
```

> The option "example" does not exist.

When putting in an obvious syntax error in `FieldTypeExampleExtension.php`, forms are still rendered without errors, leading me to believe the extension has never been loaded. The Symfony docs and [other blog posts](http://toni.uebernickel.info/2011/11/25/how-to-extend-form-fields-in-symfony2.html) suggest that it would be loaded automatically.

Is there a way to force it to load? Or otherwise implement the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The alias key of the tag is the type of field that this extension
>   should be applied to.

You not call your extension, only normal 'text' field. Alias is the key, in your example 'field', so you should do:

```
$builder->add('city', 'field', ......
```

Or if you want to extend the text field type, you will use 'text' as an alias, and change `getExtendedType()` function to return 'text'.

Comment: I needed to apply the extension to all fields, and I was able to do that by settings the alias to `form`. Thanks, your answer helped me get there.